# Checking Existence With or Without Double Bang -- if (obj.string) vs if (!!obj.string)?

Tags: javascript, typescript

What is the difference between these two checks?

`if (obj.string) { ... }`

`if (!!obj.string) { ... }`

Thanks

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript When used as a conditional, there is no logical difference.

Comment: Since the question is 'what is the difference', then that would be two extra explicit operations (!!) vs the first version which just does the truthy check.

Comment: @Taplar, Depends. A smart compiler could optimize the double-negation away.

Comment: Very true. So there's that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`!!` is used to [normalize](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10597474/589924) a "truthy" value into `true` or `false`. There's no point in doing this here. `if` is just as capable of evaluating the truth of the value as `!` is.